# Component not re-rendering on state change - Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I cannot get my component to re-render on a state change. I am fairly confident that I am not mutating the state.

#### component (Domain)

```
...
<Add
   onClick={() => {
   domain.routes.push({
     from: 'foo',
     to: 'bar'
   });
   this.props.setDomain(this.props.domainIndex, domain);
}} />
...
```

#### reducer

```
case 'SET_DOMAIN':
  let tmpState = {...state}
  tmpState.domains[action.index] = action.value;
  return {...tmpState}
```

#### action

```
export const setDomain = (index, domain) => ({
  type: 'SET_DOMAIN',
  value: domain,
  index: index
});
```

#### container

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setDomain, setRoute } from '../actions';
import Domain from '../components/pages/domain';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  domains: state.domains
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setDomain: (index, domain) => dispatch(setDomain(index, domain)),
  setRoute: (domainIndex, routeIndex, route) =>
    dispatch(setRoute(domainIndex, routeIndex, route))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Domain);
```

From the redux chrome extension I can see that `setDomain` is being called and the state is being returned correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> React Redux tries to improve performance by doing shallow equality
>   reference checks on incoming props in shouldComponentUpdate, and if
>   all references are the same, shouldComponentUpdate returns false to
>   skip actually updating your original component.
>
> It's important to remember that whenever you update a nested value,
>   you must also return new copies of anything above it in your state
>   tree. If you have state.a.b.c.d, and you want to make an update to d,
>   you would also need to return new copies of c, b, a, and state.
>
> From https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#react-not-rerendering

`{...object}` is only a shallow clone. The object's child object will still have the same reference. Therefore, to Redux, the child object is not updated.

I think the quickest way to solve this is to use Lodash [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep).

```
let tmpState = _.cloneDeep(state);
```

or

```
tmpState.domains = _.cloneDeep(tmpState.domains);
```

But this does come with a performance cost.

Alternatively, you can shallow clone the affected child 1 by 1.